# 'Lost Connection' Randomly Occurring Swift

Tags: ios, xcode

My app is Fetching CoreData strings and uiimages. I'm also capturing the camera's live feed and displaying it on a UIView. Randomly the device 'Lost Connection'. I have checked the memory and CPU Usage and nothing seems to be going wrong there.

[image: lost Connection]

I occasionally get these printout warnings

> Received memory warning.
>
> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (20)
>
> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
>
> Communications error:  { count = 1,
>   contents =    "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length =
>   22, contents = "Connection interrupted" } }>

I've tried setting my Localization native development region in the Info.plist to United States as was widely suggested but not luck.

I'm running Xcode 9 BETA and iOS 10 on my testing device (iPod).

Comment: Avoid Beta versions if possible. I got that issue because my device was consuming to much memory (it happened only on old devices, not recent ones), and I think that the iPad could have an issue.

Comment: All CD and camera activity should be on background threads - don't block the main thread.

Comment: @DavidH If I don't specify to do it in the main thread will it automatically do it in the background or do I need to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I was taking the picture returned a very high quality image (1000's of pixels). So when I passed the image in prepareForSegue and saved it using Core Data it was overloading the device.

So I used this code to reduce the size of the image and that worked.

```
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, newWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight))
    image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: newWidth,height: newHeight))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```